# Proof that if the 3-momentum is conserved then so is energy. (Weinberg's Gravitation and Cosmology)

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, conservation-laws

In section 4 chapter 2 of his book "Gravitation and Cosmology: Principles and Applications of the General Theory of Relativity", Weinberg argues that if the 3 momentum is conserved in a 'reaction', say a collision, then so is the energy. The proof begins by assuming that there are 2 frames in which the 3 momentum is conserved. Then the proof goes as shown in the figure-

[image: Weinberg's proof]

However, I don't understand what justifies the existence of another frame where the 3-momentum is conserved. Note, that just before this, he has proved that if the 4-momentum is conserved in one frame then it is conserved in another related to the first by a Lorentz transformation. However, that proof assumes the conservation of all 4 components of the momentum vector.

Comment: "In section 4 of chapter 2, " of what? Weinberg is not a book AFAIK, but a person.

Comment: Referring to the book Gravitation and Cosmology by Weinberg @annav
Have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: "I don't understand what justifies the existence of another frame where the 3-momentum is conserved." Weinberg says it is a *supposition* ("For suppose that..."), so it doesn't seem like he feels the need to justify it. It's not immediately  clear that it can be justified, but I'd like to look at the book to get some more context...

Comment: I think he means that if 3 momentum conservation is a Lorentz invariant property, it follows that the same is true for energy

Comment: @user330563 Indeed, that seems like what he's trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p^a = mu^a$ be the 4-momentum of a single particle with 4-velocity $u^a$. Also, w.r.t. to another frame (denoted by prime)

$$ {p'}^a = {\Lambda^a}_{b} p^b \,.$$

For a ensemble of $n$ particles the total 4-momentum is $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i^a$.  These particles can interact and hence change their 3-velocities. Let the net change in $p_i^a$ for each particle be $\Delta p_i^a$ (note that $p_i^a$ is only invariant for a single particle if it does not interact with others). Then, the net change for the ensemble can be written as

$$  \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta p_i^a \,. $$

But since the energy $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^0$ and 3-momentum $\Sigma_{i=1}^n p^\mu_i$ is conserved for the ensemble, so as a whole therefore (note: Greek indices run from 1-3, Latin from 0-3)

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta p_i^0 = 0 \quad {\rm and} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta p^\mu_i = 0 \,.$$

Hence

$$  \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta p_i^a = \sum_{i=1}^n (\Delta p_i^0 +  \Delta p^\mu_i) = 0 \,.$$

Now, to transform to a different frame, we can use the very first equation above. Since your question is concerned only about the 3-momentum in the new frame, so we can do

$$  \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta p_i'^\mu  =  \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda^\mu_b (\Delta p_i^b) = \Lambda^\mu_b  \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta p_i^b  = 0 $$

because the term $\sum_{i=1}^n \Delta p_i^b$ is zero.

Comment: Does this generalize to a collision? I am sorry I didn't clearly mention this in my question, but Weinberg is referring to conservation under processes like a collision, not just to free particles.

Comment: @James How about now?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to it. Aren't you assuming that the energy is conserved in some frame by writing $\sum_i^n \Delta p_i^0=0$? Also, I am unable to understand $\sum \Delta p_i^a=\sum(\Delta p_i^0+\Delta p_i^\mu)=0$. Doesn't $\Delta p^a_i$ refer to one particular component of the momentum four vector?

Comment: @James Yes I'm assuming that there is a frame where energy and momentum both are conserved.  Also $\Delta p^a_i = \Delta(p^0_i, p^1_i, p^2_i, p^3_i)$. I'm using the so-called abstract index notation there (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation#:~:text=Abstract%20index%20notation%20(also%20referred,particular%2C%20are%20non%2Dnumerical.).